# How do I store data in array within a loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I store data in array within a loop?

```
    var images;
    var i = 0;

    $('#cover div').each(function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        //I should store id in an array
    });


    <div id="cover">
        <div id="slider_1"><p class="content">SLIDER ONE</p></div>
        <div id="slider_2"><p class="content">SLIDER TWO</p></div>
        <div id="slider_3"><p class="content">SLIDER THREE</p></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this,

```
var arr = [];
i = 0;
$('#cover div').each(function()
{
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        arr[i++] = $(this).attr('id');
        //I should store id in an array
});
```

other Way for getting id using javascript object instead of jquery for increasing performance.

```
var arr = [];
i = 0;
$('#cover div').each(function()
{
      arr[i++] = this.id;
});
```

**Edit** You can also use jQuery [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUqEQ/2/)**

```
arr = $('#cover div').map(function(){
    return this.id;
});
```

Comment: Why not just `push` it onto the array instead of wasting time with a counter? Or else use the index argument to the `.each` callback function.

Comment: Any reason for not just using `arr.push($(this).attr('id'))`?? ... 4 seconds late, haha.

Comment: @Benno: Push is slower than the code-sample not using jQuery, see performance test I created: http://jsperf.com/array-push-vs-insert However, it seems push is faster than the first code-sample using jQuery to select the id. Eitherway, stick to second code-sample in that case.

Comment: Thanks for telling @ François Wahl, infact javascript gives performance over jquery usually but it is not with this case .

Comment: The reason the first one is fastest is because you aren't running an `$.attr` call though. http://jsperf.com/array-push-vs-insert/2.

Comment: Thanks @Beeno, I run the test 3 times and  arr[i++] = this.id; this one was fastest all the time, is it same on your side?

Comment: Just realised that I didn't thank so sorry for the delay and thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

javascript Arrays have a method push(el) like this:

```
var images;
var i = 0;

$('#cover div').each(function()
{
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    images.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

<div id="cover">
    <div id="slider_1"><p class="content">SLIDER ONE</p></div>
    <div id="slider_2"><p class="content">SLIDER TWO</p></div>
    <div id="slider_3"><p class="content">SLIDER THREE</p></div>
</div>
```